# Unknown code # for a consistency level

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, consistency

I am executing cql batches while reading data from a large file and in every 1000 iteration I prepare a batch query and execute.

I would like to know why am I getting error messages like: "Unknown code 192 for a consistency level". Cassandra can hundle batch size till 65536, why is it complaining with 1K?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: What is the exact code you are using, The consistency level message indicates that the code for what number of replica's need to respond is invalid

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean by the code! Maybe you can tell me where to find it. I am using the c++ driver (https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver) and in all of my queries I have kept "CQL_CONSISTENCY_ONE"!

Comment: What code are you executing. ie
cluster = Cluster('123942')
session=cluster.connect()
ect ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any code! Here is how I connect to the cluster:

```
cql::cql_initialize();
builder = cql::cql_cluster_t::builder();
builder->add_contact_point(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"));
cluster = builder->build();
session = cluster->connect();
```